# Manually edit projects installed with pip in Cloud9

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide

I have installed Django 1.8a in my Cloud9 project. Some of my dependencies haven't merged pull request making their projects compatible with Django 1.8a. I hope they will soon merge these changes but until then my project wont work with Django 1.8a.

Can I do something to update my dependencies? My dependencies are installed with pip and are located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` but I can't locate this directory in Cloud9.

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually edit any packages. Fork the repos on Github (or wherever), push your changes to those forks, then [point pip to the forked repo](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/usage.html#version-control-systems).